# How to join two tables and get specific records only

Tags: mysql

How to join two tables and get specific records only?

I have two tables

1. Supplier -- Columns (`supp_id`,`supp_code`,`supp_name`,`address`)
2. SelectedSuppliers -- columns (`supplier_id`,`is_selected`, date_a)

I load the all the suppliers to grid view and select specific suppliers by check box

For specific date from supplier table then it goes to `SelectedSupplier` table .

When I load saved suppliers from `SelectedSupplier` table I need to view all the suppliers from two tables. Which means if I added a new supplier it should be display when I'm loading second time .

This is my query

```
SELECT
    `supplier`.`supp_id`,
    `supplier`.`supp_name`,
    `supplier`.`address`,
    `supplier`.`supp_code`,
    `SelectedSuppliers `.`is_selected`
FROM 
    `SelectedSuppliers `
LEFT JOIN 
    `supplier` ON (`shop_list`.`supplier_id` = `supplier`.`supp_id`)
WHERE
    SelectedSuppliers.date_a = '2013-1-5'
```

It works but load `SelectedSupplier` records only not all records

Thanks.

Comment: If you refresh the page, it will load second time. The query doesn't says it should not take last inserted record. It will not load only if you are cache the query somewhere.

Comment: Nop, i need to get rest of the recods from supplier table that i didn't selected

Comment: You are already querying with date. When you load second time, you will get fresh copy.

Comment: mmm... i think you misunderstand the question... i meant ,  need to get records what i selected from selectedsupplier table and what i didnt select from supplier table....

Comment: Still I didn't understand your question. When you insert record in to `supplier` you will insert a record into `selectedsupplier` also ? And where exactly you want to fetch ? which table ?

Comment: sorry.. no, i insert suppliers in one form ,in second form i load all the suppliers in to grid and pick some selected suppliers according to date and insert into selectedsupplier table.... could you understand what i said here? shall i explain next part?

Comment: Have you got answer from below answers ?

Comment: yeah, i got the answer ... thank you too....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not at all clear why you have a reference to `shop_list`, when that table or alias doesn't appear in your query, or why one of your table names includes a trailing space,

From your description, I think you want `supplier` to be on the left side of the LEFT JOIN (to return all rows from the supplier table.

(I replaced the reference to `shop_list` with a reference to the `SelectedSuppliers`. I left the trailing space on the table name, as in your example query.)

```
SELECT s.supp_id
     , s.supp_name
     , s.address
     , s.supp_code
     , e.is_selected
  FROM `supplier` s
  LEFT 
  JOIN `SelectedSuppliers ` e
    ON e.supplier_id = s.supp_id
   AND e.date_a = '2013-1-5'
```

All rows will be returned from the table on the left side (in this query, that's `supplier`), along with any matching rows from the table on the right side.

The value for `is_selected` in will be NULL when there is no matching row in the SelectedSuppliers table. This can easily be replaced with a 0, if that's desired, by wrapping that in an IFNULL function.

If your intent is to EXCLUDE suppliers that are already selected, we can add a simple predicate to the query to eliminate the matching rows:

```
WHERE e.supplier_id IS NULL
```

That will return rows from `supplier` where there is no matching row in the `SelectedSuppliers` table,

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  `supplier`.`supp_id`,
  `supplier`.`supp_name`,
  `supplier`.`address`,
  `supplier`.`supp_code`,
  `SelectedSuppliers `.`is_selected`
FROM 'supplier',`SelectedSuppliers`
  LEFT JOIN `supplier`
    ON (`shop_list`.`supplier_id` = `supplier`.`supp_id`)
where SelectedSuppliers.date_a = '2013-1-5'
```

Please have a look at the image [image]

Comment: Wow...Its an amazing solution

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse the join order and move the condition into the `ON` clause to allow the left join to still work:

```
SELECT
  `supplier`.`supp_id`,
  `supplier`.`supp_name`,
  `supplier`.`address`,
  `supplier`.`supp_code`,
  `SelectedSuppliers `.`is_selected`
FROM `supplier`
LEFT JOIN `SelectedSuppliers ` 
    ON `shop_list`.`supplier_id` = `supplier`.`supp_id`
    AND SelectedSuppliers.date_a = '2013-1-5'
```

By selecting from `suppliers` first, *then* left joining  you'll get every supplier row.

Note: It is commonly (and incorrectly) believed that the `ON` clause may only have "key related" conditions, but in fact it may contain any condition (even one not related to the tables being joined!)

Answer (score 0):

Use this form

```
SELECT A1,A2,...
FROM TABLE1,TABLE2,TABLE3,....
WHERE ......
```

Note: From table names creates a cartesian product of all the values out of which you choose by specifying the where clause.

Comment: i need to get rest of the recods from supplier table that i didn't selected to selectedsupplier table

Answer (score 0):

whatever information you are putting into is_selected column to know whether that information has been supplied or not use that in your where condition. Suppose by default it is 0 (if that is not selected) and you want those records to be loaded then simply put `where SelectedSuppliers.is_selected = 0`